# Salesforce rest api invocation from mule

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex, mule-esb

I need to invoke a custom rest api in Salesforce.
Could someone please provide any details how to invoke it from mule.
Please find my mule configuration and suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

### Salesforce Custom Rest Class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/customOrder')
global with sharing class CustomOrder {


    @HttpPost
    global static Account createOrder() {
      RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
      RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
      Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString());
      ----
      ---
      Account resultAcc;
      ---
      return resultAcc
    }
  }
```

### Request payload

```
{
  "Obj1": [
    {
      "key": "data for key",
      "value": "some value"
    },
    {
      "key": "leadSource",
      "value": "Web"
    },
  "obj2": [
    {
      "key": "data for key",
      "value": true
    }
  ],
  "key1": false
}
```

### Mule Config for salesforce

```
<sfdc:config-oauth-user-pass name="Salesforce" consumerKey="XXXX" consumerSecret="XXX" username="XXX" password="XXX" tokenEndpoint="xxxxx" disableSessionInvalidation="true" doc:name="Salesforce: OAuth 2.0 Username-Password" fetchAllApexRestMetadata="true" >
       <sfdc:apex-class-names>
            <sfdc:apex-class-name>CustomOrder</sfdc:apex-class-name>
        </sfdc:apex-class-names>
    </sfdc:config-oauth-user-pass>

    <sfdc:invoke-apex-rest-method config-ref="Salesforce" restMethodName="CustomOrder||createOrder\^customOrder\^HttpPost\^Account\^" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
```

How is the best way to invoke this api from mulesoft

Answer (score 0):

For integration Mule with Salesforce via REST API you can use [Salesforce Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/salesforce-connector).

Comment: Any example for how to define "Invoke apex rest method" in salesforce connector?

Comment: It's described in mentioned documentation. Do you have some specific question?

Comment: I have followed the documentation but I am getting error. I am not able to configure properly "sfdc:invoke-apex-rest-method" , "restMethodName". I have updated the original question. Could you please suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure that I know this area so deeply, but I'd like to suggest you ask this question on salesforce.stackexchange.com too

Comment: @mule-user did you found a way to query your RestResource from Mule connector? I suspect that you can use the Mule SFDC connector only for common methods on common SFDC objects (Account, Contact, ...). Can you confirm? thanks

Comment: @Premier yes i have found a way

Comment: @mule-user can you share it? tnx